# When does !strcmp(a,b) evaluate as true?

Tags: c

If we have the code below, what is the meaning of `!strcmp(a,b)`? I know how to work with `strcmp(a,b)`, and I know if `a = b`, it returns `0`, if `a<b` it returns `-1`, and if `a>b` it returns `1`. The `!` sign should negate that function, so when does the code below return `i`? I'm confused.

```
 for(i=1;i<var;i++) 
     if(!strcmp(s,anotherVar[i]))
         return i;
```

Comment: Given `x` (where x is an int), what is the meaning of `!x`?

Comment: `if(!strcmp(s,anotherVar[i]))` means "if the strings are the same".

Comment: @ClaudiuM `!false` is `false`?

Comment: @LogicStuff suppose that x = true, !x = false

Comment: @ClaudiuM So now answer the question again, given `x` (where x is an int), what is the meaning of `!x` when you cannot just suppose that x = true?

Comment: @hvd You asked for that :) @Claudiu `!x` for an integer is `x != 0`, hope you get that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what the numeric values actually mean. When you treat a number as a Boolean condition, `0` is evaluated as `false`; anything else is evaluated as`true`. So `!0` evaluates as `true`, while `!n` evaluates as `false` for all non-zero values of `n`.

Put differently, `!strcmp(s,anotherVar[i])` is true when `s` and `anotherVar[i]` are the same (because `strcmp` returns `0`), but false when they aren't (because `strcmp` returns a non-zero value).

Here's [a live, online demo](http://ideone.com/Kc9SHm), using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char * a = "hello";
    char * b = "world";
    char * c = "hello";

    if (!strcmp(a,b)) {
        printf("true for a and b\n");
    } else {
        printf("false for a and b\n"); // this runs
    }

    if (!strcmp(a,c)) {
        printf("true for a and c\n"); // this runs
    } else {
        printf("false for a and c\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
false for a and b
true for a and c
```

Comment: I'd add that though any non-zero value is treated as true, logical and comparison operators  always return `1` for true... eg. `82 && 144` evaluates to `1` and not some other non-zero value.

Comment: @ClaudiuM I'm glad I could help you. The downvotes are probably because this question is fairly easy to answer with a little research. This site allows downvoting for a reason, and downvotes don't make people here "bad."

Answer (score 1):

`!strcmp` will return `true` if `strcmp` returns `0`.

```
if(0) //false 
if(4) //true
```